# is there any way to get plotly radar charts with a complete line using go.Scatterpolar()?

Tags: python, plotly

In plotly's example scatter radar plots ([here](https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/)), one of the line segments is missing. This is also the case when I've tried it myself - I think if you're using plotly express you can use `line_close`. Is there an equivalent in using go.Scatterpolar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [examples in the reference](https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/#basic-radar-chart-with-goscatterpolar) are created in a graph object and the lines are not closed. To close it, the data must be adjusted. This is accomplished by repeating the first point.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

r = [1, 5, 2, 2, 3]
r.append(r[0])

theta = ['processing cost','mechanical properties','chemical stability','thermal stability','device integration','processing cost']
theta.append(theta[0])

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatterpolar(
  r=r,
  theta=theta,
  fill='toself'
))

fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  height=450,
                  polar=dict(
                      radialaxis=dict(
                          visible=True
                      ),
                  ),
                  showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]